# How to Programatically Toggle a Zurb Foundation Switch Control, in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation

I would like to to dynamically toggle the state of a Zurb Foundation Switch control using javascript.

This is a default Zurb Fondation Switch:

```
<!-- Default switch --> 
<div class="switch">   
  <input id="d" name="switch-d" type="radio" checked>   
  <label for="d" onclick="">Off</label>

  <input id="d1" name="switch-d" type="radio">
  <label for="d1" onclick="">On</label>

  <span></span>
</div>
```

Demo [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/switch.html). They're based on [this project](http://ghinda.net/css-toggle-switches/), I believe.

When I tried to change the state of the switch using jquery:

```
$('#d1').attr('checked','checked'); $('#d').removeAttr('checked'); // Switch ON
$('#d').attr('checked','checked'); $('#d1').removeAttr('checked'); // Switch OFF
```

it worked in Firefox but not in Chrome. In Chrome [v25 on OSX10.8.3], the first command - Switch ON - is successful but when I try to use `$('#d').attr('checked','checked'); $('#d1').removeAttr('checked');` then it looks like the CSS is not correctly picking up the element as being checked and the display balks - see how the last Switch in the image below is not displaying the **OFF state** properly.

[image]

You can test these commands on the [Switch page](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/switch.html) of the Zurb Foundation documentation; `d` refers to the forth and largest switch you see in the list at the top of the page.

Comment: Can you not fire the event which would normally modify the state of the control?

Comment: Do you know what that is? It's undocumented and I couldn't see it in the source. But agreed, this would be the best approach.

Comment: You could also type in the console:  $("#elem").click to see the code attached to the event

Comment: Well, that's a face-slap for me for not simplifying things like this. However, it still doesn't work - I can only switch ON, not OFF.

Comment: This is because (for some weird reason) the elements ID changes when it's state is modified (examine the element before and after... The click will work with the new ID, if you can accommodate the pattern for the ID change it will work.

Comment: OK, yes, just saw that. Got it - thank you for showing me the obvious. Wood for the trees and all that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can directly call the click function on the element.

```
$("#d1").click(); // Switch ON
```

The issue you will have is that the ID of the element changes so it will be slightly more tricky, you can use smarter selectors to get to the element.
Once the elements state has changed you will note that the ID has changed to:

```
$("#d").click(); // Switch OFF
```

This will now toggle you back into an off state.

Cheers Oliver.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, if you are uncomfortable with simulating a click, you can use jQuery's [#prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead.

```
$('input:not([checked])').prop('checked', true);
$('input[checked]').prop('checked', false);
```

Possible use case: inside an error handler of an AJAX call that was fired on click.

Comment: 'input:checked' seems to work better as a selector.  input[checked] only returns elements which were checked on page load, while input:checked catches those that have been switched after page load.

Comment: Interesting - I didn't know about that selector. Thanks for your comment!